# What is the most battery-efficient way of monitoring proximity to a number of locations in Android?

Tags: android, android-location, geofencing, android-geofence

I have an app which will take some (internet) action every time the user approaches any one of a set of locations (for example, let's say it notifies a server whenever I am near a Starbucks shop, so my coffee habits can be analysed).

What's the most battery-efficient (yet reliable and relatively accurate) way of causing the phone to do something whenever it's at a certain location? I don't need perfect location accuracy - within 50m or so is fine.

Currently, I set a ProximityAlert for each location with a 100m radius, and have it raise an Intent, which is then served by a Service which runs in the background. The service also includes an Alarm which causes a download every three hours or so.

The Service itself doesn't appear to drain any significant amount of battery - the battery is all drained by "Android OS". According to the Android 4.1.2 Battery monitor, Android OS is using 3x as much CPU as a phone without my app, and has "stay awake" on for most of the time.

Would changing it to an IntentService make a difference?

Would reducing (or increasing) the radius of the alert make a difference?

Would converting it to a Geofence (https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) make much difference?

Can I set it to use a cheaper location service unless it thinks it's close to one of the locations (or will it do that automatically?)

Comment: maybe you should try [Geofencing APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) - [references](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html)

Comment: Thanks - added this to the question

Answer (score 2):

I have never worked with the LocationManagers proximity alert functions, so I do not really know how much they drain the battery, but as far I know the new Geofence services (https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) were specially designed in a battery-friendly fashion.

Comment: Thanks, I had briefly forgotten about this option.

Answer (score 1):

LocationManagers pose a very difficult way to program something that you need. Google has reinvented its location providers to fuse them with sensors. Its the latest and best, uses less battery and does **magic** with your application, by removing all the 1000's of lines of useless code that you need to write between your gps / network providers.

The new api's are LocationClient api's. Watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc&list=WLRNCZT9Eq_HTG5jIEFxMpdqoXZBNalekx) and demo for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you can use new geo fence api provided by the Google recently,its more power efficient
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html